# Spring 3.1: Non-XML equivalent of annotation-driven transaction management

Tags: java, spring

What is the non-XML (in `@Configuration`) equivalent of `<tx:annotation-driven>` in Spring 3.1?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Spring 3.1 has [`@EnableTransactionManagement`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html) annotation for this purpose.